# In Android Studio how can you access the 'COMPILER ERROR OUTPUT'?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error:

```
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException:       
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

But I do not seem to find out how to access the 'compiler error output'. Why is it that its very hard to find?

Comment: Where is that message appearing? The Gradle Console view (docked lower-right by default) is where the entire build process output goes.